# Generate PDF on client side using JSPDF

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, pdf-generation, jspdf

In my application I need to download pdf by parsing HTML on client side itself. For generating pdf on client side I am using jsPdf. Following is my code.

**PdfGenerator.java**

```
public static native String createPDF() /*-{
        $wnd.createPDF(); 
}-*/;
```

**entrypoint.html**

```
 function createPDF(){
         try {
          var doc = new jsPDF();
           doc.text(20, 20, 'This PDF has a title, subject, author, keywords and a crea');
           doc.output('datauri');
           var out = doc.output();
           var url = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + Base64.encode(out);
           document.location.href = url;
        } catch (e) {
            return e.message;
        }
        return "";
};
```

I have added all the js in my project and defined script as well. But whenever I call this method then it is giving output **"sprintf is not defined."**.
Please let me know if I am missing out something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you forget to add the scripts for `sprintf.js` and `base64 js`. As `jsPdf.js` internally uses both of these js.

**entrypoint.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sprintf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>
```

please refer this link http://forums.webhosting.uk.com/web-designing-development/6718-jspdf-generating-your-pdf-web-page-documents-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 1):

In the latest builds of jsPDF, you don't need base64 or sprintf, just jspdf.min.js found in the 'dist' folder, includes all the plugins (except downloadify/swfobject).

Just updating an old ticket if someone runs across it when trying to figure out jsPDF due to it's not so good documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to complicate your code by using `window.location`.
JsPDF has method `.save()` to handle it.

```
function createPDF(){
         try {
           var doc = new jsPDF();
           doc.text(20, 20, 'This PDF has a title, subject, author, keywords and a crea');
           doc.save('file_name.pdf');
        } catch (e) {
            return e.message;
        }
        return "";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browser you are supporting (all browser versions, and IE 10+), you don't even need to include `Base64.encode()`. Just call `btoa()` instead.